# Improving Blender Selection Time

Tags: selection-tools

New to Blender. I am editing a large .obj file to mass delete unneeded portions to decrease file size for a navigation mesh. Selecting a portion of the map takes a long time, up to two minutes sometimes. My memory and CPU are not maxing out on my computer. I was wondering if anyone had any advice on what could be going on here and possibly what I can do to improve the time it takes for a selection to complete?

Comment: The select tool operating speed mainly depends on the CPU performance. Is it too much Boolean modifier(exact solver) in your scene? You are select in object mode or edit mode? amount of vertices?

Comment: I am in edit mode and the amount of vertices is 1,187,874 (a huge reason why I am editing this file to drastically reduce this number). I have friends that can load this file into their blender and no real wait on selection time.

Comment: I assume it may be my CPU but its only sitting at 40% utilization when I'm waiting for a selection to complete.

Comment: In my case, 12,582,912 vertics for a single object it takes around 4 second on every large select. May be it just the hardware problem. Try to use different computer to test.